# How do I sum all the items of a list of integers in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of integers, like:

```
val myList = listOf(3,4,2)
```

Is there any quick way in Kotlin to sum all the values of the list? or do I have to use a loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the `.sum()` function to sum all the elements in an array or collection of `Byte`, `Short`, `Int`, `Long`, `Float` or `Double`. ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html))

For example:

```
val myIntList = listOf(3, 4, 2)
myIntList.sum() // = 9

val myDoubleList = listOf(3.2, 4.1, 2.0)
myDoubleList.sum() // = 9.3
```

If the number you want to sum is inside an object, you can use `sumOf` to select the specific field you want to sum: ([docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html))

```
data class Product(val name: String, val price: Int)
val products = listOf(Product("1", 26), Product("2", 44))
val totalCost  = products.sumOf { it.price } // = 70
```

Note: `sumBy` was deprecated in Kotlin 1.5 in favour of `sumOf`.

Answer (score 17):

The above answer is correct, as an added answer, if you want to sum some property or perform some action you can use sumBy like this:

sum property:

```
data class test(val id: Int)

val myTestList = listOf(test(1), test(2),test(3))

val ids = myTestList.sumBy{ it.id } //ids will be 6
```

sum with an action

```
val myList = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

val addedOne = myList.sumBy { it + 1 } //addedOne will be 65
```

Comment: sumBy allows integers only so far. So if you are trying with floats it will not work.

Comment: sumBy was deprecated. From now on use sumOf

Answer (score 13):

The above answers are correct but, this can be another way if you also want to sum all integers, double, float inside a list of Objects

```
list.map { it.duration }.sum()
```

Comment: You can just do `list.sumOf { it.duration }`

Answer (score 6):

`sumBy` is Deprecated new use `sumOf` instead

```kotlin
val data = listOf(listOf(1, 2, 3), listOf(4, 5, 6))
println(data.sumOf { it.size }) // 6
println(data.sumOf { innerList -> innerList.sumOf { it } }) //21
println(data.sumOf { innerList -> innerList.sum() }) // 21
```